# Secant Method for finding $\sup f^{-1}(0)$

Tags: optimization, numerics, rootfinding

Let $f \in C^0[0, 1]$, and suppose $f \ge 0$. How can I compute $\sup f^{-1}(0)$ efficiently?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I disagree with the Bot's assessment of this question. I think the question is very concrete.

Comment: @JoeShmo note the "bot" comment is actually from an anonymous reviewer. Some details that might help a potential answerer: 1. What have you tried already (to avoid getting a suggestion that you already tried, but doesn't work/isn't efficient enough) 2. (May just be me) I'm confused by the meaning of $\sup f^{-1}(0)$. If the sup is the supremum, isn't that the least upper bound of a set? $f^{-1}(0)$ should just be a single value unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @Tyberius Yes, $\sup$ is the supremum, or the least upper bound. $\sup f^{-1}(0)$ doesn't have to be a single value - consider $f: [0, 1] \rightarrow [0, 1]$ defined by $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in [0, \frac{1}{2}]$, and $f(x) = 2(x - \frac{1}{2})$ for $x \in (\frac{1}{2}, 1]$. Then $f \in C^0[0, 1],\ f^{-1}(0) = [0, \frac{1}{2}]$, and $\sup f^{-1}(0) = \frac{1}{2}$. I have tried the secant method, and variations of it (the method of false position), as well as playing with several hyper parameters.

Comment: It works to an extent, but the results aren't the quality that I would expect, and the procedure converges slowly. Surely this is a well known problem, and there should exist some root-finding/optimization algorithm out there that fits the bill.

Comment: So you want to find the largest root of $f$. Note that most root-finding algorithms will only reliably find roots with sign changes (with multiplicity one if $f$ were smooth enough to define this). /// All root-finding solvers are in the end local algorithms, as they only use local information to define their steps. They can not give information of how a root is related to other roots. For such global information you would need bounds on the variation of the function and a sufficiently dense sampling. Continuous functions without further qualification can be rather wild.

Comment: @LutzLehmann OK, can you refer me to (optimization, most likely) methods that assume continuity? I have access to $f$, but not $\nabla f$, say. I should still probably be able to approximate $\nabla f$ via some numerical method.

Comment: As @LutzLehmann said, root-finding works better at sign changing. Because $f\geq 0$, $f$ is always positive or $0$. Maybe it is easier to min $f$, and all the minimizers of $f$ should be a root of $f=0$, because the minimum of $f$ is $0$. $\nabla f$, numercial or not, will be useful for minimizing $f$.

Comment: But a minization algorithm can only find local minima, so you will need to first filter the global ones from them.

Comment: Yes, I am after something like that. Also note that $g(x) = f(x) - 0.001$ has, in practice, negative and positive values to the left and right of the relevant root $\sup g^{-1}(0)$, but this procedure converges slowly. Any advice?

Answer (score 5):

If you need a certified result, you can try interval methods such as the ones in https://github.com/JuliaIntervals/IntervalRootFinding.jl/ . They are at their best for (at least) piecewise differentiable functions; other types of functions will of course be hard to express as functions in a programming language.

The algorithm will give you a tight inclusion for the set of zeros of a function, in cases that are not problematic numerically, with the guarantee that it's not missing a zero.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, @federico-poloni

Answer (score 0):

For reference, the Method of False Position converged accurately and fast for the function

$\exp \big(-1000 \cdot (f(x) - 0.001) \big) - 1$

Comment: I think that this should be added to the question since it does not answer it.

Comment: @nicoguaro this does answer the question. this isn't the only answer, and I welcome more, if anybody has any more answers. If $ℎ()= \exp(−1000⋅(f()−0.001))−1$, then $ℎ()=0⟹()≈0$, and this procedure converges fast (at least in the cases I ran).

Comment: How does this find the largest root and not some other root? For what function $f$ does this actually converge quickly? What were your bounds with false position? There's a lot missing here before it can be said that this properly answers the question.